# Initialize a vector of shared pointers in varidic data structures

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, initializer-list

I'm playing with variadic structures, and I'm like a kid with a box of matches.  The goal is to initialize a vector of base class pointers using parameter pack expansion.
Given:

```
   struct base {
     base() {};
     virtual ~base() {};
     ...
   };

   template<class T>
   struct derived : public base {
     derived() {};
     virtual ~derived() {};
     ...
   };

   struct collection {
     collection() 
       : a{ make_shared<derived<int>>(),
            make_shared<derived<float>>(),
            make_shared<derived<double>>() } {};
     ~collection() {};
     vector<shared_ptr<base>> a;
     ...
   };
```

Is it possible to set the items in the vector using pack expansion? The following doesn't compile, but you get the idea.  Argument lists would also be nice.

```
    template<class ...t>
    struct collection2 {
      collection2() : a{ make_shared<derived<t>>... } {}; //????
      ~collection2() {};
      vector<shared_ptr<base>> a;
    };
```

So you should be able to declare it like this:

```
    int main() {
      collection2<int,float,double> a;
      return 0;
    }
```

Anyway thanks for your input or suggestions to alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt is almost right.  You're just missing `()` to call `make_shared`:

```
template<class ...t>
struct collection2 {
  collection2() : a{ make_shared<derived<t>>()... } {};
  ~collection2() {};
  vector<shared_ptr<base>> a;
};
```

Comment: Well don't I feel silly.  I thought there was more too it than that.  Thank You!